# How to find a list of jar files that contains a particular class in unix

Tags: bash, unix

I want to find a list of jar files that contains a given , by searching in a particular directory (DIR) and all its sub directories.

I tried below command. But it provided all the classes that contains the CLASS FILE name. 
Eg : If the class is `Message.class`, following command out put the `HttpMessage.class` like class as well.

```
find <DIR> -name '*.jar' | while read F; do (echo $F; jar -tvf $F | grep <class>) done - prints the jar name if the class exists then prints the class name.
```

Comment: try `grep "\b$class\b"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `grep` can find the matched jar, however, it cannot list the namespace of the class.

Below command combined with `find` and `jar` commands, it will print out **the class with package name** and also the **jar file name**.

```
find . -type f -name '*.jar' -print0 |  xargs -0 -I '{}' sh -c 'jar tf {} | grep Message.class &&  echo {}'
```

You can also search with your package name like below:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jar' -print0 |  xargs -0 -I '{}' sh -c 'jar tf {} | grep com/mypackage/Message.class &&  echo {}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a program I developed just for this problem: https://github.com/javalite/jar-explorer

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexes in grep to specify the exact matching criteria. If you want the line to end with */Message.class*, you can do something like this:

`grep '/Message.class$'`

Answer (score 0):

You can also try **grep -iRl "name_of_your_class"**