# How to find jars having one string matched and one string unmatched in linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to find jars which is having a string "hello" but should not contain string "helloworld".
I tried the command like below,

```
find . -iname '*.jar' -printf "unzip -c %p | grep -q 'hello' && grep -qL 'helloworld' && echo %p\n" | sh
```

which is not giving correct jars.Would like to know the command for passing two conditions in grep?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952678/how-to-find-a-list-of-jar-files-that-contains-a-particular-class-in-unix

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "*.jar" -exec bash -c 'f={};jar tf $f| grep "hello" | grep -q -v "helloworld" && echo $f' \;
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  But that's irrelevant - you shouldn't answer off-topic questions - instead, please flag them
for attention and they will be closed or migrated
appropriately.

Comment: The above command giving bash: jar: command not found
bash: jar: command not found
bash: jar: command not found
bash: jar: command not found
bash: jar: command not found

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
find . -iname '*.jar' | grep hello | grep -v helloworld
```

Comment: Although this code may be help to solve the problem,
providing additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value, particularly when answering such an unclear question.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation and clarify what you think the problem actually means.

Comment: Hi Assaf, the above command still giving jars have helloworld.